# WebGL: Why I get the elongated rectangle instead of a square?

Tags: javascript, webgl

WebGL. I try to draw a point by the [WebGL Programming Guide book](https://sites.google.com/site/webglbook/) (chapter 2). But I get the elongated rectangle instead of a square (Google Chrome v79.0.3945.88 and Firefox v71.0):

[image]

Why does it happen? This is my code:

```
function main(){
    const canvasId = "my-canvas";
    const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    if(!canvas){
        console.log(`Canvas element with id = '${canvasId}' not found.`);
        return;
    }
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    if(!gl){
        console.log(`Can't to get WebGL context.`);
        return;
    }
    gl.clearColor(0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    const vshader_src = `
    void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 10.0;
    }`;
    const fshader_src = `
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }`;
    if(!initShaders(gl, vshader_src, fshader_src)){
        console.log(`Can't initialize shaders.`);
        return;
    }
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS,0,1);
}
```

My full code sources of this example is [here](https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/webgl-sandbox) (in the `src/code/lib/` subdirectory there are auxiliary files used in the book).

Comment: The code in the tutorial seems to be different then your example http://rodger.global-linguist.com/webgl/ch02/HelloPoint2.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no bugs in the code you posted.

```js
function main(){
    const canvasId = "my-canvas";
    const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    if(!canvas){
        console.log(`Canvas element with id = '${canvasId}' not found.`);
        return;
    }
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    if(!gl){
        console.log(`Can't to get WebGL context.`);
        return;
    }
    gl.clearColor(0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    const vshader_src = `
    void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 10.0;
    }`;
    const fshader_src = `
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }`;
    if(!initShaders(gl, vshader_src, fshader_src)){
        console.log(`Can't initialize shaders.`);
        return;
    }
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS,0,1);
}

// guessed implemenetation of `initShader`
// note this is BAD code. shaders should not be global like this
// The code should be calling `gl.useProgram` outside this
// function as any normal webgl app will have more than one shader program
function initShaders(gl, vsrc, fsrc) {
  const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vsrc, fsrc]);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  return program;
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

If your bug is somewhere else then you need to put that code **in the question itself** otherwise the question is off topic for stack overflow.

The only thing that would make that happen is if CSS is [setting the different display size for the canvas](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html).

Might I suggest you read [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: you are right the reason of such behavior was CSS-style. The problem is solved. Thank you for the usefull links! 